# Misuse of query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85MWK.png)I have this query which i am making use of to fetch my data.

```
public void loadQuestions() {
        try {

            String sql = "select * from "
                    + hommer.getSelectedItem()
                    + "where id= ?";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, getCount());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                question_space.setText(rs.getString("questions"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

if i am to make use of `String sql = "select * from list_of_questions where id =?";` it will definitely give out the required data from the selected table, but i do like to get the table name from a string selected by the user.

Above is the error i am seeing if i should call the `loadQuestions()` method.
I will definitely appreciate every kind gesture.

Comment: I don't see the error, but I assume it is related to the fact that there is no space between `hommer.getSelectedItem()` and `where` in the String concatenation.

Comment: `id` is int or varchar ?

Comment: @Compass looks like it to me, add a space in the + " where id= ?" line. Should fix it.

Comment: thanks @JacobH it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i actually did was just to add a space to the where statement as suggested by @JoshH.

```
public void loadQuestions() {
        try {

            String sql = "select * from "
                    + hommer.getSelectedItem()
                    + " where id= ?";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, getCount());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                question_space.setText(rs.getString("questions"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

This helped to get what i actually wanted.